# TypeORM+Postgres: values in nullable columns deleted after server restart?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm, nodemon, typegraphql

Any idea why columns defined as `nullable` in TypeORM have their values deleted after every (nodemon) server restart? Is this expected behaviour?

[image]

After restart:

[image]

The column definition:

```
      @Column({ nullable: true }) // TypeORM decorator
      @Field(_type => Number, { nullable: true })  // TypeGraphQL decorator
      rating: Rating;  // for reference: type Rating = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, with `nullable` columns. Deleted **dist/build** folder fixed it!